# Is there a way to replace key-value pairs within a dictionary by specific values from another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

**The following three dictionaries are given:**

The information has been extracted from a tree structure.
The dictionaries show the parent-child relationship.

```
root
|
|_A
| |__C
| |
| |__D
|    |
|    |__E
|    |  
|    |__F
|
|__B

dict1 = {"A":300, "B":200}
dict2 = {"A": {"C":100, "D":200}}
dict3 = {"D": {"E":100, "F":100}}
```

**The result should look like this:**

```
dict_result = {"C":100, "E":100, "F":100, "B":200}
```

"A" (key and value) in Dict1 should be replaced with the value from Dict2 with the key "A". The same should be applied for "D" in Dict2 with the specific value from Dict3.
The order of the result should look like showed above in dict_result.

I tried some recursive stuff and with a try, I combined all the dicitonaries into one nested one, but I still can't find a solution

```
dict_nested = {"A":{"C":100, "D":{"E":100, "F":100}}, "B":200}
```

additional Information:

- Dict1 has already Information about "A". But there is some more specific information within other sources which we dont want to loose.
- The order of every Dictionary is important and should not changed.
- Dtypes of keys are always strings / Dtypes of values are either Integers or another dictionary (somtimes nested).

Comment: "The following two dictionaries are given:" Those are 3 dictionaries :| I don't understand the rules being described here. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: dict1 has a value for A. Why does this value have to be updated by the value in dict2? is the order of the dictionaries important? What if dict2 would have a value for C? Would then dict 3 have to be updated with the value in dict2?

Comment: The dictionaries are not ordered, they retain insertion order

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Alexander sorry about that, post is edited.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Dict2 gives more specific Information about "A",  Thats why it should be replaced in Dict1 with the Values from Dict2. The Problem is in the Additional Dictionaries, there is sometimes the same issue that there are more specific Information elsewhere.

Comment: @Robain Interesting edit! So putting aside all of your explanation of the solution you have in mind, it looks like your actual goal is to collect all the leaf nodes of the graph being represented by these dictionaries. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming all the rest of the dictionaries are similar in type to dict2 and dict3 (and only dict1 is different), you can use the following recursion:

```
from typing import List, Dict

def func(dct: Dict[str, int], rest: List[Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]]):
    if not rest:
        return dct
    first = rest[0]
    res = {}
    for key, value in dct.items():
        if key in first:
            res.update(first[key])
        else:
            res[key] = value
    return func(res, rest[1:])
```

And then, to use it in the following way:

```
dict1 = {"A":300, "B":200}
dict2 = {"A": {"C":100, "D":200}}
dict3 = {"D": {"E":100, "F":100}}
func(dict1, [dict2, dict3])  # {'C': 100, 'E': 100, 'F': 100, 'B': 200}
```

Comment: There is no reason for the recursion in this case. Recursion is pretty slow and memory-inefficient in python, and in this case it can be simply replaced with a loop `for first in rest:`

Comment: @Stef I agree, I don't know what is the purpose of the question. The question mentioned recursive trials so I assumed this is the required direction...

Comment: @Razko Thank you for helping. There is no recursion required its just something i thought may could help. The structure of the dictionaries arent always the same sadly. Any Value of a key could also hold another dictionary

Comment: @Robain In case of such nested dictionaries, what should be the result?
Can you provide a more 'complex' example?